# Projects Using art-template which depends on acorn Encounter Invalid Unicode Escape Character Errors in Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, unicode, node.js-fs, acorn

I have been using art-template as a template engine for my project, but I recently encountered an issue that prevents the project from compiling correctly on Windows.

I've created a simple example to reproduce the problem, and the steps are straightforward:

0. Environment Details:

- Operating System: Windows 10 or 11
- Node.js Version: v14,v16, v18, v20

1. Create an empty project, and add the following to your `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "acorn-invalid-unicode-escape-sequence",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "art-template": "4.13.0"
  }
}
```

2. Install the dependencies:

```
yarn install # or npm install
```

3. Run the following code in your console, and you'll see an error:

```
node -e "require('art-template/lib/precompile.js')"
```

You will then see the following exception:

[image: Error Screenshot]

*Note*: Why is it dependent on `art-template/lib/precompile.js` rather than `acorn`? Because directly depending on `acorn` does not produce an error.

After some basic debugging, I found the issue within the `node:inspect/modules/cjs/loader Module._extensions['.js']` method:

[image: Debug Screenshot]

The `fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8')` call returns incorrect file content, and everything following `\uff21-\uf` is filled with blanks, causing a JavaScript runtime error. This is likely a bug in the `fs` module. Is there anyone who can help resolve this issue? Thank you very much！